# How to create universal confirm dialog in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I tested this custom confirmation dialog:

```
public void initConfirmDialog(String confirmMessage)
    {

        // Error Dialog Stage init
        final Stage dialog = new Stage();
        // If you want to freeze the background during dialog appearence set Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL
        // or to allow clicking on the mainstage components set Modality.NONE
        // and set dialog.showAndWait();
        dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        // Button "Yes"
        Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");
        Button btnNo = new Button("No");

        btnYes.setStyle("-fx-background-color:\n"
                + "        rgba(0,0,0,0.08),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#9a9a9a, #909090),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(white 0%, #f3f3f3 50%, #ececec 51%, #f2f2f2 100%);\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: 4,4,3;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: 7 36 6 36;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: #242d35;\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 13px;");

        btnYes.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                // TODO
                // call method
            }
        });

        btnNo.setStyle("-fx-background-color:\n"
                + "        rgba(0,0,0,0.08),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#9a9a9a, #909090),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(white 0%, #f3f3f3 50%, #ececec 51%, #f2f2f2 100%);\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: 4,4,3;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: 7 36 6 36;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: #242d35;\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 13px;");

        btnNo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                dialog.close();     // Close the dialog
            }
        });

        // Layout for the Button
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.getChildren().add(btnYes);
        hbox.getChildren().add(btnNo);

        // Image
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("/images/dialog-warning.png").toExternalForm());

        // Layout for the Label and hBox
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.getChildren().add(iv);

        // Text
        Text t = new Text();
        t.setText(confirmMessage);
        t.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));

        // Layout for the Button
        HBox thbox = new HBox();
        thbox.setSpacing(10);
        thbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 90));   // Place the dialog text right
        thbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        thbox.getChildren().add(t);

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ffffff,#f3f3f4);\n"
                + "    -fx-border-width: 1 1 1 1;\n"
                + "    -fx-border-color: #b4b4b4 transparent #b4b4b4 transparent;\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 1.083333em;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: #292929;");

        bp.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 10, 15));
        //Button btnTop = new Button("Top");
        bp.setTop(null);
        //Button btnLeft = new Button("Left");
        bp.setLeft(vbox);
        //Button btnCenter = new Button("Center");
        bp.setCenter(thbox);
        //Button btnRight = new Button("Right");
        bp.setRight(null);
        //Button btnBottom = new Button("Bottom");
        bp.setBottom(hbox);

        // Stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 140);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.setTitle("Confirm Dialog");
        Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/dialog-warning.png").toExternalForm());
        dialog.getIcons().add(icon);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

I'm looking for a lay to make this confirm dialog universal. For example I will have many cases in which I will have to call methods to execute some action. I cannot have confirm dialog for any case. Is there any universal solution?

Comment: not sure, but think that DataFx (or JFXtra) comes with convenience dialogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What You ask is not a simple task.

I ended up writing a rather complex class (still a work in progress) doing many things, including data entry, validation and generic method call on events.

I attach my current code, but:

1. it uses MigPane for layout.
2. it uses jidefx for validation (with some very ugly personal overridings, not included).
3. it uses jidefx for decoration.
4. code is provided as-is with NO warranty of any kind, of course.

You may want to simplify the code to remove unneeded dependencies (I already commented out Validation stuff).

Here are some examples:
[image: FXDialog examples]

NOTE: I started from something I found on internet (Copyright (c) 2013, Alvin Cris Tabontabon), but to date almost no original code is left; I just kept the aspect (along with some .css settings), which I like.

```
package it.condarelli.javafx.dialog;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
//import jidefx.scene.control.decoration.DecorationPane;
//import jidefx.scene.control.validation.ValidationEvent;
import net.miginfocom.layout.CC;
import net.miginfocom.layout.LC;

import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.MigPane;

import it.condarelli.javafx.css.StyleManager;
//import it.condarelli.javafx.validation.ValidationUtils;

public class FXDialog {

    private ImageView               icon;
    private Label                   lblHeader;
    private Label                   lblMsg;

    private Button                  btnAccept;
    private Button                  btnDecline;
    private Button                  btnCancel;

    private TextField               inputField;
    private CheckBox                ckbAction;

    private MigPane                 root;
    private Response                response;

    protected Stage                 primaryStage;
    private MigPane                 pneButtons;

    private MigPane                 pneCustom;

    /**
     * protected enum used to model a user's choice in confirmation dialogs
     */
    protected enum Response {
        APPROVE(true), DECLINE(false), CANCEL(null);
        private Boolean val;

        private Response(Boolean val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public Boolean getValue() {
            return val;
        }
    }

    public enum ButtonSet {
        DELETE_OPTION(), YES_NO_OPTION(), YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION(), ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION(), OK_OPTION(), OK_CANCEL_OPTION();
    }

    public enum Type {
        CONFIRMATION, INPUT, MESSAGE, CUSTOM;
    }

    public enum Severity {
        ERROR("error.png", "-fx-background-color: red;"), INFORMATION("information.png", "-fx-background-color: blue;"), WARNING("warning.png", "-fx-background-color: orange;"), QUESTION(
                "question64.png", "-fx-background-color: gold;");
        private String  ico;
        private String  css;

        private Severity(String ico, String css) {
            this.ico = ico;
            this.css = css;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the textual filename of a specific image file that has to be
         * displayed as an icon for a certain Severity value
         * 
         * @return the textual icon-filename
         */
        protected String getIcon() {
            return ico;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the textual css info for a certain Severity value
         * 
         * @return the textual icon-filename
         */
        protected String getCss() {
            return css;
        }
    }

    private double  initX;  // X-Coordinate location of the dialog
    private double  initY;  // Y-Coordinate location of the dialog

    // inits this object with a modal stage
    protected FXDialog(Type type, String header, String message) {
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        MigPane inner = new MigPane(/*"debug"*/);
        lblHeader = new Label(header);
        lblHeader.getStyleClass().add("fxdialog-header");
        inner.add(lblHeader, "dock north, gaptop 7, gapbottom 5");
        icon = new ImageView(/*new Image(FXDialog.class.getResource("icons/question64.png").toExternalForm())*/);
        inner.add(icon, "dock west, gapright 5");
        if (message != null) {
            lblMsg = new Label(message);
            lblMsg.getStyleClass().add("fxdialog-message");
            inner.add(lblMsg, "wrap");
        }
        switch (type) {
        case CONFIRMATION:
            break;
        case CUSTOM:
            pneCustom = new MigPane(new LC()/* .debug() */);
//          inner.add(new DecorationPane(pneCustom));
            inner.add(pneCustom);
            break;
        case INPUT:
            pneCustom = new MigPane(new LC()/* .debug() */);
            inputField = new TextField();
            pneCustom.add(inputField);
            inner.add(pneCustom);
            break;
        case MESSAGE:
            break;
        }
        pneButtons = new MigPane(new LC().align("right", "center"));
        inner.add(pneButtons, "dock south");

        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
        ds.setHeight(25);
        ds.setRadius(12);
        ds.setWidth(25);
        inner.setEffect(ds);
        inner.getStyleClass().add("fxdialog");

        root = new MigPane();
        root.getStyleClass().add("fxdialog-root");
        //root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        root.add(inner);
        // root.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box, #000, 10, 1.0, 0, 0);");

        //root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("FXDialog.css").toExternalForm());
        StyleManager.add("FXDialog", getClass().getResource("FXDialog.css").toExternalForm());
        StyleManager.register("FXDialog", root);
        primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                case ENTER:
                    if (btnAccept != null)
                        btnAccept.fire();
                    break;
                case ESCAPE:
                    if (btnDecline != null)
                        btnDecline.fire();
                    break;
                default:
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        });

    }

    protected void setButtons(ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        setButtons(buttonSet, null);
    }

    protected void setButtons(ButtonSet buttonSet, String cbLabel) {
        if (buttonSet == null)
            buttonSet = ButtonSet.OK_OPTION;
        switch (buttonSet) {
        case DELETE_OPTION:
            btnAccept = new Button("Delete");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnDecline = new Button("Don't Delete");
            btnDecline.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnDecline.requestFocus();
            btnDecline.setPrefWidth(80.0);
            break;
        case YES_NO_OPTION:
            btnAccept = new Button("Yes");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnAccept.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnAccept.requestFocus();
            btnDecline = new Button("No");
            btnDecline.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            break;
        case OK_CANCEL_OPTION:
            btnAccept = new Button("Ok");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnAccept.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnAccept.requestFocus();
            btnDecline = new Button("Cancel");
            btnDecline.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            break;
        case YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION:
            btnAccept = new Button("Yes");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnAccept.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnAccept.requestFocus();
            btnDecline = new Button("No");
            btnDecline.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
            btnCancel.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            break;
        case ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION:
            btnAccept = new Button("Accept");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(80.0);
            btnAccept.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnAccept.requestFocus();
            btnDecline = new Button("Decline");
            btnDecline.setPrefWidth(80.0);
            break;
        case OK_OPTION:
        default:
            btnAccept = new Button("Ok");
            btnAccept.setPrefWidth(70.0);
            btnAccept.setDefaultButton(true);
            btnAccept.requestFocus();
        }
        if (cbLabel != null) {
            ckbAction = new CheckBox(cbLabel);
            pneButtons.add(ckbAction, "tag left");
        }
        if (btnCancel != null) {
            btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    setReponse(Response.CANCEL);
                    primaryStage.close();
                }
            });
            pneButtons.add(btnCancel, "tag cancel");
        }
        if (btnDecline != null) {
            btnDecline.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    setReponse(Response.DECLINE);
                    primaryStage.close();
                }
            });
            pneButtons.add(btnDecline, "tag no");
        }
        if (btnAccept != null) {
            btnAccept.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    setReponse(Response.APPROVE);
                    if (cbAction != null && ckbAction.isSelected()) {
                        String value = (inputField != null) ? inputField.getText() : null;
                        rtnObject = cbAction.doit(value);
                    }

                    primaryStage.close();
                }
            });
            pneButtons.add(btnAccept, "tag yes");
        }
    }

    private Boolean open() {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                initX = me.getScreenX() - primaryStage.getX();
                initY = me.getScreenY() - primaryStage.getY();
            }
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                primaryStage.setX(me.getScreenX() - initX);
                primaryStage.setY(me.getScreenY() - initY);
            }
        });
//      ValidationUtils.initialize(pneCustom);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        StyleManager.unregister(root);
        return response.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * The purpose of this method is to retain the selected action in the
     * confirmation dialog.
     * 
     * @param response
     */
    protected void setReponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    /**
     * Static method responsible for the displaying of a customizable message
     * box.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            : the actual message to display in the message box
     * @param title
     *            : the title of the message dialog
     * @param messageType
     *            : available message types are: INFORMATION, WARNING, ERROR,
     *            each one with its graphical style
     */
    public static void showMessageDialog(String message, String title) {
        showMessageDialog(message, title, Severity.INFORMATION);
    }

    public static void showMessageDialog(String message, String title, Severity severity) {
        FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.MESSAGE, title, message);

        dialog.setKind(severity);
        dialog.setButtons(ButtonSet.OK_OPTION);

        dialog.open();
    }

    protected void setKind(Severity severity) {
        icon.setImage(new Image(FXDialog.class.getResource("icons/" + severity.getIcon()).toExternalForm()));
        //lblHeader.setStyle(severity.getCss());
        for (Severity s : Severity.values())
            root.getStyleClass().remove(s.name());
        root.getStyleClass().add(severity.name());
    }

    /**
     * Static method responsible for the displaying of a dialog box with custom
     * FX content.
     * 
     * @param content
     *            : a Region representing the content to be added to the dialog
     *            stage
     * @param title
     *            : the title of the dialog
     * @param messageType
     *            : available message types are: INFORMATION, WARNING, ERROR,
     *            each one with its graphical style
     * @return
     */
    public static Boolean showCustomDialog(Region content, String title) {
        return showCustomDialog(content, title, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static Boolean showCustomDialog(Region content, String title, Severity severity) {
        return showCustomDialog(content, title, severity, ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION);
    }

    public static Boolean showCustomDialog(Region content, String title, Severity severity, ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        FXDialog dialog = newCustomDialog(content, title, null, null, severity, buttonSet);
        return dialog.open();
    }

    private static FXDialog newCustomDialog(Region content, String title, String prompt, Callable<?> action, Severity severity, ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        final FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.CUSTOM, title, null);

        dialog.setKind(severity);
        dialog.setButtons(buttonSet, prompt);

        content.styleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if (newValue.contains(";"))
                    dialog.btnAccept.setDisable(true);
                else
                    dialog.btnAccept.setDisable(false);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }

    public static FXDialog newCustomDialog(String title, Severity severity) {
        final FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.CUSTOM, title, null);
        dialog.setKind(severity);
        return dialog;
    }

    private String      cbLabel;
    private Callable<?> cbAction;
    private Object      rtnObject;

    public void addAction(String prompt, Callable<?> action) {
        cbLabel = prompt;
        cbAction = action;
    }

    public TextField addTextField(String label) {
        final Label l = new Label(label);
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setUserData(l);
        pneCustom.add(l);
        pneCustom.add(tf, new CC().growX().wrap());
        if (inputField == null)
            inputField = tf;
        tf.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                l.setVisible(newValue);
            }
        });
        return tf;
    }

    public CheckBox addCheckBox(String label) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(label);
        pneCustom.add(cb, "wrap");
        return cb;
    }

    public <T> ComboBox<T> addComboBox(String label, ObservableList<T> items) {
        Label l = new Label(label);
        ComboBox<T> cb = new ComboBox<>(items);
        cb.setUserData(l);
        pneCustom.add(l);
        pneCustom.add(cb, new CC().growX().wrap());
        return cb;
    }

    public Boolean open(ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        setButtons(buttonSet, cbLabel);
//      ValidationUtils.addGlobalValidator(pneCustom, ValidationEvent.VALIDATION_INFO, (EventHandler<ValidationEvent>) ev -> {
//          btnAccept.setDisable(ValidationUtils.compare(ev, ValidationEvent.VALIDATION_INFO) > 0);
//      });
        return open();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return rtnObject;
    }

    /**
     * Static method responsible for the displaying of a confirmation dialog
     * box, providing a simple binary choice against some question.
     * 
     * @param caption
     *            : the text of the question to ask to the user
     * @param title
     *            : the title of the confirmation dialog
     * @param confirmType
     *            : available confirmation types are: DELETE_OPTION,
     *            YES_NO_OPTION, ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION, each one to set a
     *            different text for the binary choice buttons that will appear
     * @return
     */
    public static Boolean showConfirmDialog(String caption, String title, ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        return showConfirmDialog(caption, title, buttonSet, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static Boolean showConfirmDialog(String caption, String title, ButtonSet buttonSet, Severity severity) {
        FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.CONFIRMATION, title, caption);

        dialog.setKind(severity);
        dialog.setButtons(buttonSet);

        return dialog.open();
    }

    /**
     * Static method responsible for the displaying of an input dialog box,
     * providing an input field to type some (short) text in.
     * 
     * @param caption
     *            : the text of the message to display
     * @param title
     *            : the title of the input dialog
     * @return some input text the user typed in
     */
    public static String showInputDialog(String caption, String title) {
        return showInputDialog(caption, title, ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static String showInputDialog(String caption, String title, ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        return showInputDialog(caption, title, buttonSet, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static String showInputDialog(String caption, String title, Severity severity) {
        return showInputDialog(caption, title, ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION, severity);
    }

    public static String showInputDialog(String caption, String title, ButtonSet buttonSet, Severity severity) {
        FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.INPUT, title, caption);

        dialog.setKind(Severity.QUESTION);
        dialog.setButtons(ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION);

        dialog.inputField.requestFocus();

        return (dialog.open() ? dialog.inputField.getText().trim() : null);
    }

    public static abstract class Callable<T> implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<T> {
        protected String    input;

        private T doit(String input) {
            this.input = input;
            try {
                T t = call();
                return t;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static Object showExtendedInputDialog(String caption, String title, String prompt, Callable<?> action) {
        return showExtendedInputDialog(caption, title, prompt, action, ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static Object showExtendedInputDialog(String caption, String title, String prompt, Callable<?> action, ButtonSet buttonSet) {
        return showExtendedInputDialog(caption, title, prompt, action, buttonSet, Severity.QUESTION);
    }

    public static Object showExtendedInputDialog(String caption, String title, String prompt, Callable<?> action, Severity severity) {
        return showExtendedInputDialog(caption, title, prompt, action, ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, severity);
    }

    public static Object showExtendedInputDialog(String caption, String title, String prompt, Callable<?> action, ButtonSet buttonSet, Severity severity) {
        FXDialog dialog = new FXDialog(Type.INPUT, title, caption);

        dialog.setKind(severity);
        dialog.setButtons(buttonSet, prompt);

        if (!dialog.open())
            return null;

        String value = dialog.inputField.getText().trim();
        if (dialog.ckbAction.isSelected()) {
            Object o = action.doit(value);
            if (o != null)
                return o;
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected Object userObject;
    public void setData(Object obj) {
        userObject = obj;
    }
    public Object getData() {
        return userObject;
    }
    public static void setVisible(Node node, boolean b) {
        node.setVisible(b);
        Object o = node.getUserData();
        if (o instanceof Node) {
            ((Node) o).setVisible(b);
        }
    }
    // load a custom css File
    public void loadCSS(File f) {
        if (f.exists()) {
            try {
                root.getStylesheets().add(f.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a test program:

```
package it.condarelli.javafx.dialog;

import it.condarelli.javafx.dialog.FXDialog.Callable;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.MigPane;
//import it.condarelli.javafx.validation.ValidationUtils;

/**
 * Class used to demonstrate all of the custom dialogs types' behaviour
 * 
 * @author Mauro Condarelli
 *
 */
public class TestMain extends Application {

    /**
     * Method used to demonstrate the working of MessageDialogs, InputDialogs,
     * and ConfirmDialogs
     */
    public void start1() {
        FXDialog.showMessageDialog("This is a demonstration of Information message \ndialog.", "Title (INFORMATION)", FXDialog.Severity.INFORMATION);
        FXDialog.showMessageDialog("This is a demonstration of Warning message \ndialog.", "Title (WARNING)", FXDialog.Severity.WARNING);
        FXDialog.showMessageDialog("This is a demonstration of Error message \ndialog.", "Title (ERROR)", FXDialog.Severity.ERROR);
        String input = FXDialog.showInputDialog("Enter your favorite number:", "Title (INPUT)");
        System.out.println(input);

        boolean confirm = FXDialog.showConfirmDialog("Do you really want to delete the selected item?", "Title (DELETE_OPTION)", FXDialog.ButtonSet.DELETE_OPTION);
        if (confirm)
            System.out.println("Accepted!");
        else
            System.out.println("Declined!");

        confirm = FXDialog.showConfirmDialog("Do you really want to delete the selected item?", "Title (ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION)", FXDialog.ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION);
        if (confirm)
            System.out.println("Accepted!");
        else
            System.out.println("Declined!");

        confirm = FXDialog.showConfirmDialog("Do you really want to delete the selected item?", "Title (YES_NO_OPTION)", FXDialog.ButtonSet.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (confirm)
            System.out.println("Accepted!");
        else
            System.out.println("Declined!");
    }

    /**
     * Method used to demonstrate the working of a CustomDialog
     */
    public void start2() {
        FXDialog fxd;
        CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3;
        TextField tf;
        ComboBox<String> cb;
        Boolean res;

        fxd = FXDialog.newCustomDialog("Dialog Title Here", FXDialog.Severity.WARNING);
        cb1 = fxd.addCheckBox("Simple checkbox");
        cb2 = fxd.addCheckBox("Three state checkbox");
        cb2.setAllowIndeterminate(true);
        cb2.setIndeterminate(false);
        cb3 = fxd.addCheckBox("Disabled");
        cb3.setSelected(true);
        cb3.setDisable(true);
        res = fxd.open(null);
        System.out.println("showCustomDialog returned " + res);
        System.out.println("showCustomDialog returned " + res + "(" + (cb1.isSelected() ? "X" : " ") + ")");

        fxd = FXDialog.newCustomDialog("Dialog Title Here", FXDialog.Severity.WARNING);
        cb1 = fxd.addCheckBox("Simple checkbox");
        cb2 = fxd.addCheckBox("Three state checkbox");
        cb2.setAllowIndeterminate(true);
        cb2.setIndeterminate(false);
        cb3 = fxd.addCheckBox("Disabled");
        cb3.setSelected(true);
        cb3.setDisable(true);
        res = fxd.open(FXDialog.ButtonSet.ACCEPT_DECLINE_OPTION);
        System.out.println("showCustomDialog returned " + res + "(" + (cb1.isSelected() ? "X" : " ") + ")");

        fxd = FXDialog.newCustomDialog("Dialog Title Here", FXDialog.Severity.INFORMATION);
        tf = fxd.addTextField("Name:");
//      ValidationUtils.install(tf, ValidationUtils.getDoubleValidator());
        cb = fxd.addComboBox("Type:", FXCollections.observableArrayList("pippo", "pluto", "paperino"));
//      ValidationUtils.install(cb, ValidationUtils.getComboBoxValidator());
        res = fxd.open(null);
        System.out.println("showCustomDialog returned " + res);
        if (res) {
            System.out.println("   '" + tf.getText() + "'");
            System.out.println("   '" + cb.getValue() + "'");
        }

        fxd = FXDialog.newCustomDialog("Dialog Title Here", FXDialog.Severity.INFORMATION);
        tf = fxd.addTextField("Name:");
//      ValidationUtils.install(tf, ValidationUtils.getIntegerValidator());
        cb = fxd.addComboBox("Type:", FXCollections.observableArrayList("pippo", "pluto", "paperino"));
//      ValidationUtils.install(cb, ValidationUtils.getComboBoxValidator());
        fxd.addAction("do it", new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("handler has been called ("+input+")");
                return null;
            }
        });
        res = fxd.open(FXDialog.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        System.out.println("showCustomDialog returned " + res);
        if (res) {
            System.out.println("   '" + tf.getText() + "'");
            System.out.println("   '" + cb.getValue() + "'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method that adds two buttons to the primary stage, each one dedicated to
     * launch a demo on some type of custom dialogs.
     * 
     * @param primaryStage
     *            : the primary Stage for this Application
     */
    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

        MigPane root = new MigPane("wrap 1", "[fill]");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // String insetTextCss =
        // getClass().getResource("InsetTextButton.css").toExternalForm();

        Button b1 = new Button("Some simple Dialogs");
        b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                start1();
            }
        });
        root.add(b1);
        Button b2 = new Button("Some more complex Dialogs");
        b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                start2();
            }
        });
        root.add(b2);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Main function.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            : the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

... and accompaining .css

```
.fxdialog { 
    -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(white,#DDDDDD);
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
}
.fxdialog-root {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.fxdialog-header {
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-text-aligment: center;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font: 32px bold;
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 -11 0 -11;
}
.ERROR       .fxdialog-header {-fx-background-color: red;}
.INFORMATION .fxdialog-header {-fx-background-color: blue;}
.WARNING     .fxdialog-header {-fx-background-color: orange;}
.QUESTION    .fxdialog-header {-fx-background-color: gold;}
.fxdialog-message {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
}
.button {
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(33, 248, 33, .4);
    -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
}
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell:busy {
    -fx-graphic: url("icons/link.png");
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 248, 33, .4);
    -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste here the final result, please?

Comment: @Peter Penzov where es it.condarelli.javafx? the source is incompleted

Answer (score 1):

`Button` have a `onActionProperty()` so if you have acces to your button you can set this property to define the action you want execute when the user click on it.

```
    button.onActionProperty().set(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            //Here your action
        }
    });
```

So if you give access to your button onactionproperty you will can define easely there action

Comment: If I understand you correctly I have to send the Java method which I want to call as Object to `onActionProperty()`?

Comment: For example in the class you want to use your popup, to configure it you can do something like popup.getButton.onActionProperty().set(yourEventHandler) , with that when you'll call your popup the button will react to yourEventHandler